# Decode nested JSON struct as Data in Swift

Tags: json, swift, jsondecoder

I have a struct `Message` in Swift, which has a property `data`.

```swift
struct Message {
  let id: Int
  let data: Data
}
```

I want to decode the struct `Message` from JSON, where it's `data` property's underlying type cannot be determined. An example JSON would be like:

```json
{
  "id": 3,
  "data": {
    "name": "Bob",
    "age": 32
  }
}
```

or:

```json
{
  "id": 3,
  "data": {
    "location": "New York",
    "data": "2022-3-1"
  }
}
```

Therefore, I'd like to store the `data` as type `Data`, and defer the actual decoding of `data` to later time. Now, I just want to store the raw data. How should I achieve that in Swift? Thanks for helping.

Comment: You can’t decode json into Data and you can’t decode only part of the json so the answer is you cannot do this.

Comment: That's right but you might have a work-around; https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46999079/swift-4-decodable-decoding-json-object-into-data

Comment: You get `Data` only if the API sends something like base64 encoded bytes. If the structure of the JSON cannot be determined use `JSONSerialization`. The magic of `Codable` is based on (rather) predictable JSON. Somewhere there is a `AnyCodable` implementation, but the effort is much higher and the efficiency is much lower than traditional `JSONSerialization`.